# A single page website using multiple Ruby on Rails controllers/views with sliding page transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I cant imagine this to be very complicated, however my level of Rails is very basic.
The idea is that I am going to make a website which is going to have multiple pages, and sections (as you would conventionally have). 
Each page will obviously have a view/layout/partial etc.
So now, I want to make the website have one page,or at least to the user seem like one page, however there will always be a banner/header present at the top. The idea is that any link that is clicked on the top will automatically scroll the user down to the correct place, without the page having to reload again (seemless). The problem I would face is the URL controller problems, if it is a one page website how can I change the URL?
I would like to know if someone has a solution to this style of design/development using rails.

An example is this : [www.smokeybones.com](http://www.smokeybones.com/)

The database would be linked to the menu and the items in the menu, so that would be my model so to speak.

Many Thanks

Comment: their urls don't change because it is just a single page with vertical scroll and horizontal sliders. You will not have url controller issues since you will only have one controller and one action, main#index or whatever. All your sub models, aka pages will be loaded into index view and rendered as part of that one page.

Comment: so basically everything will be on one page, and one very long action? I may be able to use partials to split each 'page' I guess. one of the things I wanted to know was that how in Ruby on Rails could I get transitions like that, or seemless scrolling? is that simply CSS?

Comment: Yes it just css/js, if you need to have a back end of some sort for managing parts/areas of the page, order of items, assets etc. then it makes sense to use rails. Otherwise it's just a single page website, no need to over think it.

Comment: not sure why people grade down questions, there are "no" stupid questions.

Comment: Thankyou. Lastly say for example, someone clicks one link, but right clicks and says open link in a new tab, that will refresh the page, how to I get the page to load at the anchor point of the link they have clicked on a fresh page load?

Comment: You keep anchors in the url as parameters. Kind of like this page ... http://901.com/#small-talk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use Rails for that? 
Why do you need model for that?
If you want to link on the same page elements - just use anchors in your links.

Comment: I will be using anchors, however I still need to have an MVC in place because there is some dynamic content on the website

Comment: Will I basically have one controller, with different actions inside it?

Comment: One action is enough for one page.

Answer (score 1):

Just use page anchors. This page here does something very similar http://www.kemperwebteam.com

```
<a href="#page1">Navigate to Page 1</a>
...
<h1 name="page1">Page 1 Content</h1>
```